# How to set default value for empty CSV fields when using mongoimport

Tags: mongodb, mongoimport

Is there anyway to specify default values for empty cells when using `mongoimport` to import a CSV file.

I import CSV data like this:

```
usename,password,salt
xxx@ss.com,12345,,
xxx@ss.com,asdf,,
xxx@ss.com,ads,,
```

but I want to set `salt` to some default value like `saltdefault`.
How can I achieve that with `mongoimport`, or do you have some other way to realize it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge there is no such thing like default values for importing CSV values via `mongoimport`.

But you can of course prepare the data upfront by using some script, e.g. the following python script would do the job when called with the input CSV file as argument

```
import csv
import sys

in_name = sys.argv[1]
out_name = in_name + '.post' 

with open(in_name, newline="") as in_f, open(out_name, "w", newline="") as out_f:
    reader = csv.reader(in_f)
    writer = csv.writer(out_f)

    # Keep heading
    row = next(reader) 
    writer.writerow(row)

    for row in reader:   
        if len(row[2]) == 0:
            row[2] = 'Your default' 
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Another solution is to first import your data into a MongoDB collection and then run an update command against it filling the documents with empty `salt`.

Comment: I will choose second solution. But there is some data in my cluster, so i will build a singleton mongodb to hand these csv data first, my English is poor, Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I understood your question and that's the whole point of language - communication; so don't worry :)